# CONCATENATE is not working in interop excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

[image]

I am creating excel using formula =CONCATENATE(A1,":",B1)-CONCATENATE(C1,":",D1) programmatically using C#
but I got error while adding semicolon ":" in programmatically

help me to solve this problem

Error: HRESULT:0X800A03EC

```
OSheet.Cells[1,1] = 10;
OSheet.Cells[1,2] = 30;
OSheet.Cells[1,3] = 5;
OSheet.Cells[1,4] = 25;
OSheet.Cells[1,5].Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A1,:,B1)-CONCATENATE(C1,:,D1)";
OSheet.Cells[1,5].NumberFormat = "hh:mm";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said works in Excel and what you write in your c# code are not the same thing :

```
C#: "=CONCATENATE(A1,:,B1)-CONCATENATE(C1,:,D1)"
XL:  =CONCATENATE(A1,":",B1)-CONCATENATE(C1,":",D1)
```

See the difference? In your c# you have dropped the quotes around the colons

Make your c# like:

```
OSheet.Cells[1,5].Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A1,\":\",B1)-CONCATENATE(C1,\":\",D1)";
```

Putting a slash before the quote tells c# "this quote is part of the string, rather than ending the string"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OSheet.Cells[1,5].Formula = "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1-C1,"00"),":",TEXT(B1-D1,"00"))";
```

See [Text function doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c).